# Pullback of a complex one-form

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, complex-geometry, pullback, exterior-derivative

Let f be a holomorphic function from $\mathbb{C}^n$ to $\mathbb{C}^n$. Let $g_j$ be the jth coordinate function from $\mathbb{C}^n$ to $\mathbb{C}$.

Show that $f^*dz_j$= $\partial g_j$.

I understand that this $\partial g_j$ means the Dolbeaut operator of first taking exterior derivative and then projecting on the (1,0) component.

I tried writing $dz_j=dx_i+idy_j$ and taking $f^*$ of that. Then I distributed $d$ linearly but I cannot see how to get to $\partial g_j$.

Help?

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you're writing $g_j$ for the $j$th component function of $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that because $f$ is holomorphic, each component $f_j$ is holomorphic, and so $\bar\partial f_j = 0$. On the other hand, because
$$df_j = d(f^*z_j) = f^*dz_j,$$ 
we conclude that $f^*dz_j = df_j = \partial f_j + \bar\partial f_j = \partial f_j$.